# How do I highlight a HTML button using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to highlight the "current page" in my navigation menu (with drop-down menus).

[image]

The code below did the job when I had simple navigation links (built using the "< a >" HTML tag). I am now upgrading my navigation bar to hold drop-down menus (using "< button >" HTML tags).

I believe I need to take a similar approach and assign an active class to the "current" page but I can't work out how to loop through "< button >" objects in the same way I did for "< a >" objects

How can I dynamically highlight the current page in my navigation bar when using buttons ("< button >") in my navigation bar?

I found a related article on W3: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_active_element2 but it doesn't work for my use-case as I'm navigating between different URLs.

A simplified version of my code looks like this:

```
<div class="navigation">

  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="page_a.html">Page A</a>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn" onclick="location.href='page_b.html'" type="button"> Page B</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="page_b.html#food">Food</a>
      <a href="page_b.html#exercise">Exercise</a>
      <a href="page_b.html#drinks">Drinks</a>
    </div>
  </div> 

  <a href="page_c.html">Page C</a>  
  <a href="page_d.html">Page D</a>
</div>

<!-- Highlight current page (works for <a> but not <button>)-->
<script>
  $(function(){
      $('a').each(function(){
          if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
              $(this).addClass('active'); 
              $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
          }
      });
  });


</script>
```

Associated CSS:

```
...
.active {
  background-color: blue;
}
...

.dropdown:not(.dropdown-content) {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  margin: 0;
}

...

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add the class active to each page so the when the user is on the home page. your code would be like this.

```
 <a class='active' href="index.html">Home</a>
```

For page A

```
  <a class='active' href="page_a.html">Page A</a>
```

Comment: Tip: instead of `href="index.html"` please use `href="/"` and instead of `href="page_a.html"` use `href="/page_a.html"`. This works much better.

Comment: I was hoping for the solution to be dynamic as I have extracted the navigation bar to a separate HTML file (to avoid having to paste it separately into each page's HTML file) so cannot add the class='active' into the navigation

Comment: You would need to add get variables to the included page banner.html?thispage='home' then add the active class to the correct link that way.