# Main page textarea changes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

If anyone from the forum can help it would be much appreciated.

Here is a script I have, by clicking a button, textarea changes, but the issue I have is the page always opens with a `textarea.one` visible as in CSS I have `display:none` for `textarea.two` and `textarea.three`.

My question is if before this page I have another page with 3 links and by clicking

link 1 - this script opens, `textarea.one` is visible, `textarea.two` and `textarea.three` are hidden.
link 2 - this script opens, `textarea.two` is visible, `textarea.one` and `textarea.three` are hidden.
link 3 - this script opens, `textarea.three` is visible, `textarea.one` and `textarea.two` are hidden.

Something similar to the language selection, if I have selected language on the page, it already knows that it should start with `textarea.two` visible instead of `textarea.one` and all similar pages will be opened based on this first choice of 'language'.

```js
function hide1() {
  document.querySelector("textarea.one").style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector("textarea.two").style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector("textarea.three").style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector("button.menucopy1").style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector("button.menucopy2").style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector("button.menucopy3").style.display = "none";
}

function hide2() {
  document.querySelector("textarea.one").style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector("textarea.two").style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector("textarea.three").style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector("button.menucopy1").style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector("button.menucopy2").style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector("button.menucopy3").style.display = "none";
}

function Copytextfunction2() {
  var value = document.getElementById("myInput2").value;
  var copyText = document.createElement("textarea");
  copyText.value = value;
  copyText.style.position = "fixed";
  copyText.style.top = "-1000vh";
  document.body.append(copyText);
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  document.execCommand("copy");
  console.log(value);
  copyText.remove();
}

function Copytextfunction3() {
  var value = document.getElementById("myInput3").value;
  var copyText = document.createElement("textarea");
  copyText.value = value;
  copyText.style.position = "fixed";
  copyText.style.top = "-1000vh";
  document.body.append(copyText);
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  document.execCommand("copy");
  console.log(value);
  copyText.remove();
}

function Copytextfunction1() {
  var value = document.getElementById("myInput1").value;
  var copyText = document.createElement("textarea");
  copyText.value = value;
  copyText.style.position = "fixed";
  copyText.style.top = "-1000vh";
  document.body.append(copyText);
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  document.execCommand("copy");
  console.log(value);
  copyText.remove();
}

function hide3() {
  document.querySelector("textarea.one").style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector("textarea.two").style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector("textarea.three").style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector("button.menucopy1").style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector("button.menucopy2").style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector("button.menucopy3").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<textarea class="one" id="myInput1" name="myInput1" readonly>
One
One
One</textarea>
</div>

<div class="textniz">
  <textarea class="two" id="myInput2" name="myInput2" readonly>
Two
Two
Two</textarea>
</div>

<div class="textniz">
  <textarea class="three" id="myInput3" name="myInput3" readonly>
Three
Three
Three</textarea>
</div>


<div class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="logo" href=".//templates/chat.html">test</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <button class="menu">menu</button>

  <button class="image">image</button>

  <button onclick="hide1()" class="en">hide1</button>
  <button onclick="hide2()" class="gr">hide2</button>
  <button onclick="hide3()" class="ru">hide3</button>

  <button onclick="Copytextfunction1()" class="menucopy1">copy1</button>
  <button onclick="Copytextfunction2()" class="menucopy2">copy2</button>
  <button onclick="Copytextfunction3()" class="menucopy3">copy3</button>
</div>
```

Hopefully, this is clear enough, I have made huge progress with the help of this forum, but unfortunately, as I move forward there is more and more I cannot figure out on my own, so whoever will be able to help it would be appreciated.

Comment: you forgot provide css. Also, what is the question again?

Comment: Hi, wasn't sure how to add both HTML and CSS in one message.

Comment: I will try to write an example here. Lets imagine I am on the page 1, I have 3 links on that page, first link will leads me to the page with the code "snippet" and instead of three textareas visible at once I see the first one.

Comment: If I select the second link, it leads me to the same page, but the second textatea is visible and the rest remain hidden.

Comment: If I select third link it opens the page with a code, where textarea.three is visible and textarea.one and textarea.two are hidden. Hope this is clear enough, let me know if you need CSS.

Comment: use "edit the above snippet" link when editing your post.

Comment: @Edvard If an answer helped you, then please mark it as correct.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, I wasn't able to do it. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code and set links like this for textarea 1:
`<a href="yourdomain.com/url?textarea=1">This link will show textarea 1 and hide the others.</a>`

Please note the changes made to your functions and the html where `id` is used instead of `class`.

But let me tell you, what you are trying to achieve is very definitely better done in another way.

```js
// Get textarea from url parameters
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let textarea = urlParams.get('textarea')

function show(textarea) {
  for (let check = 1; check <= 3; check++) {
    document.getElementById('myInput' + check).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('menucopy' + check).style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById('myInput' + textarea).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('menucopy' + textarea).style.display = "block";
}

function Copytextfunction(textarea) {
  var value = document.getElementById('myInput' + textarea).value;
  var copyText = document.createElement("textarea");
  copyText.value = value;
  copyText.style.position = "fixed";
  copyText.style.top = "-1000vh";
  document.body.append(copyText);
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
  console.log(value);
  copyText.remove();
}

// Run the hide function with the textarea number from parameters
if (textarea) {
  show(textarea);
}
```

```html
<div class="textniz">
  <textarea id="myInput1" name="myInput1" readonly>
      One
      One
      One
    </textarea>
</div>

<div class="textniz">
  <textarea id="myInput2" name="myInput2" readonly>
      Two
      Two
      Two
    </textarea>
</div>

<div class="textniz">
  <textarea id="myInput3" name="myInput3" readonly>
      Three
      Three
      Three
    </textarea>
</div>


<div class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="logo" href=".//templates/chat.html">test</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <button class="menu">menu</button>

  <button class="image">image</button>

  <button onclick="show(1)" id="en">hide1</button>
  <button onclick="show(2)" id="gr">hide2</button>
  <button onclick="show(3)" id="ru">hide3</button>

  <button onclick="Copytextfunction(1)" id="menucopy1">copy1</button>
  <button onclick="Copytextfunction(2)" id="menucopy2">copy2</button>
  <button onclick="Copytextfunction(3)" id="menucopy3">copy3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this code too and it's not working too.

Comment: Works with your link exactly as I need it to work, I can change textarea=1,2,3 and displays one of three. In my script however, I still see all the buttons and all 3 text areas at the same time.

Comment: Does your link have any css?

Comment: Thank you, sorry I am new to coding. Now it seems to be working! Much appreciated!

Comment: Hi, not sure if I can ask in the same question. Is there a way to highlight the active button after it's clicked or the link is used? E.g. hide3 button is clicked and it's highlighted in red or  textarea=3 used in the link and hide3 button is once again highlighted.

Comment: You should ask another question or search. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66190076/how-do-i-highlight-a-html-button-using-css

Answer (score 2):

First of all, inline style should only be reserved as a last resort, use classes instead.
Second, avoid duplicating code, use centralized function for common usage.

If I understood you correctly, you need make one page to "communicate" with another page somehow? For that you can either use url parameters or hash `#mydata`, cookies or localStorage.

Here is an example of using localStorage to store the selected textarea id:

https://jsfiddle.net/veo6thy0/
Every time you refresh the page, it will show last shown textarea

```js
let taId;
try
{
  taId = localStorage.getItem("taId"); //get stored id
}
catch(e){}

if (!document.getElementById(taId))
  taId = document.querySelector(".textniz textarea").id; //fallback to default first textarea

show(taId); //show text area

function show(taId) {
  document.body.setAttribute("show", taId);
  try
  {
    localStorage.setItem("taId", taId); //store textarea id
  }
  catch(e){}
}

function Copytextfunction(taId)
{
  var value = document.getElementById(taId).value;
  var copyText = document.createElement("textarea");
  copyText.value = value;
  copyText.style.position = "fixed";
  copyText.style.top = "-1000vh";
  document.body.append(copyText)
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
  console.log(value)
  copyText.remove()
}
```

```css
textarea[data-ta], /* hide textareas */
.menucopy[data-ta] /* hide copy buttons */
{
  display: none;
}

body[show="myInput1"] [data-ta="myInput1"],
body[show="myInput2"] [data-ta="myInput2"],
body[show="myInput3"] [data-ta="myInput3"]
{
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="textniz">
  <textarea class="one" id="myInput1" name="myInput1" data-ta="myInput1" readonly>
One
One
One</textarea>
</div>

<div class="textniz">
  <textarea class="two" id="myInput2" name="myInput2" data-ta="myInput2" readonly>
Two
Two
Two</textarea>
</div>

<div class="textniz">
  <textarea class="three" id="myInput3" name="myInput3" data-ta="myInput3" readonly>
Three
Three
Three</textarea>
</div>


<div class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="logo" href=".//templates/chat.html">test</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <button class="menu">menu</button>

  <button class="image">image</button>

  <button onclick="show(this.dataset.ta)" class="en" data-ta="myInput1">textarea1</button>
  <button onclick="show(this.dataset.ta)" class="gr" data-ta="myInput2">textarea2</button>
  <button onclick="show(this.dataset.ta)" class="ru" data-ta="myInput3">textarea3</button>

  <button onclick="Copytextfunction(this.dataset.ta)" class="menucopy" data-ta="myInput1">copy1</button>
  <button onclick="Copytextfunction(this.dataset.ta)" class="menucopy" data-ta="myInput2">copy2</button>
  <button onclick="Copytextfunction(this.dataset.ta)" class="menucopy" data-ta="myInput3">copy3</button>
</div>
```

P.S.
Just a little clarification in case it's too confusing. This code uses `data-*` attributes to "link" textareas with it's corresponded buttons. That attribute also used in CSS to hide/display needed textareas and "copy" buttons. The value of that attribute can be accessed in javascript via `dataset` property of the element, i.e. attribute `data-blah="ok"` in javascript can be accessed via `myElement.dataset.blah`